# boto3 s3 copy access denied

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to run a lambda that copies a file from a public folder to my s3 bucket.

```
vendor_bucket = 'mogreps-uk'
vendor_key = 'prods_op_mogreps-uk_20130102_03_00_006.nc'

vendor_source = {'Bucket': vendor_bucket, 'Key': vendor_key}

destination_bucket = 'sudi-mogrep-source'
destination_key = vendor_key

print(destination_bucket)
print(destination_key)
print(vendor_source)

s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=destination_key, CopySource=vendor_source)
```

This is my serverless.yaml permissions:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "s3:List*"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:GetObject"
  Resource:
    - "arn:aws:s3:::sudi-mogrep*"
    - "arn:aws:s3:::sudi-mogrep*/*.*"
```

I am getting the following error on invocation:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied: ClientError
```

Something must be wrong with the way I am setting up the permission. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I think your lambda doen't have a permission to access this bucket. Did you attach a role to it? (the role with a policy that would allow this lambda to PUT into the bucket). I never used serverless.yaml, I just attach a role that consists of one or two policies; it usually works fine

Comment: Please confirm that your Lambda function has GetObject permissions on the source _object_ and PutObject permissions on the destination _bucket_.